# Multiple edits without changing anything?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I just flagged this for moderator attention. **Q:** Was this the correct action?

I got one of these suggested-edits in my review queue and found out the user had edited **all posts** in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163289/laravel-4-unable-to-generate-a-url-for-the-named-route-login-as-such-route-do) question, just replacing the content... with the same content.

[image]

Did the user misunderstood the highlight edit or is this a typical abuse to get some points? Or is it me judging wrong and it was a valid edit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the "side-by-side markdown" view of the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15163289/revisions): the user's adding syntax highlighting.

This is fine, although probably a bit of a waste of time on the editor's part. I'm fixing the Laravel tags to support highlighting, so these edits shouldn't be necessary in the future.

Comment: So flag valid or invalid? It seems a waste of reviewer's time, the same thing over and over and over. Or am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: @Undo A helpful edit is a helpful edit, and I wouldn't expect a new user to know they should come to meta to ask for syntax highlighting support. No time wasted here far as I'm concerned. It's good that Sergio, as a more experienced user, raised the issue here so that it could be taken care of in a better way.